EPPlus: Not able to hide the Data row while creating pivot table
I have created a pivot table using EPPlus library using C# console application.
This is the current code:
using OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;
using OfficeOpenXml;

namespace EPPlus_POC
{
    public class TransactionEPPlus
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string Items { get; set; }
        public string TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public string PostingDate { get; set; }
        public string DueDate { get; set; }
        public double TransactionAmount { get; set; }
        public double TransactionAmountReporting { get; set; }
    }

    public static class EPPlusExample
    {
        public static void CreatePivotTable(List<TransactionEPPlus> transactions)
        {
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                // Add a worksheet
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Transactions");
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet2 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Transactions-Pivot");

                // Load the data into the worksheet, starting from cell A1
                worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(transactions, true);

                // Define the data range
                var dataRange = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, transactions.Count + 1, 7];

                // Add a pivot table
                var pivotTable = worksheet2.PivotTables.Add(worksheet2.Cells["A1"], dataRange, "PivotTable");

                // Configure the values
                var tAmount = pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["TransactionAmount"]);
                tAmount.Format = "#,##0.00";
                pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["TransactionAmountReporting"]);

                // Configure the rows
                pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["CustomerName"]);
                pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Items"]);
                var tDate = pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["TransactionDate"]);
                tDate.Name = "Transaction date";
                pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["PostingDate"]);
                pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["DueDate"]);

                // Configure subtotals and grand totals
                pivotTable.RowFields[0].SubTotalFunctions = eSubTotalFunctions.Default; // No subtotals for all rows except CustomerName
                pivotTable.RowFields[0].Outline = false;
                pivotTable.RowFields[0].Compact = false;
                for (int i = 1; i < pivotTable.RowFields.Count; i++)
                {
                    pivotTable.RowFields[i].SubTotalFunctions = eSubTotalFunctions.None;
                    pivotTable.RowFields[i].Outline = false;
                    pivotTable.RowFields[i].Compact = false;
                    pivotTable.RowFields[i].ShowInFieldList = true;
                }
                pivotTable.RowGrandTotals = true; // Show grand totals for columns
                pivotTable.ColumnGrandTotals = false; // Do not show grand totals for rows

                // Display in tabular form
                pivotTable.PivotTableStyle = PivotTableStyles.Light15;
                pivotTable.Compact = true;
                pivotTable.CompactData = true;
                pivotTable.UseAutoFormatting = true;
                pivotTable.ShowMemberPropertyTips = false;
                pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;
                pivotTable.RowHeaderCaption = "Customer name";
                pivotTable.ShowValuesRow = false;
                pivotTable.DataCaption = "wow";
                // SHow filter for all the columns except calculated fields
                foreach (var pivotField in pivotTable.Fields)
                {
                    pivotField.Outline = false;
                    pivotField.Compact = false;
                }

                worksheet.Hidden = eWorkSheetHidden.VeryHidden;

                // Save the Excel package to a file
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("EPPlus.xlsx");
                package.SaveAs(fileInfo);

                Console.WriteLine("Excel file created successfully!");
            }
        }
    }
}

And the Program.cs class looks like this:
using EPPlus_POC;

List<TransactionEPPlus> transactions = new List<TransactionEPPlus>
{
    new TransactionEPPlus { CustomerName = "Customer A", Items = "Item 1", TransactionDate = "06/10/2024", PostingDate = "06/10/2024", DueDate = "06/10/2024", TransactionAmount = 10900.55, TransactionAmountReporting = 900400 },
    new TransactionEPPlus { CustomerName = "Customer B", Items = "Item 2", TransactionDate = "06/10/2024", PostingDate = "06/10/2024", DueDate = "06/10/2024", TransactionAmount = 20560.78, TransactionAmountReporting = 180870 },
    new TransactionEPPlus { CustomerName = "Customer B", Items = "Item 2", TransactionDate = "12/10/2024", PostingDate = "06/10/2024", DueDate = "06/10/2024", TransactionAmount = 25000.43, TransactionAmountReporting = 330600 },
    new TransactionEPPlus { CustomerName = "Customer C", Items = "Item 3", TransactionDate = "12/10/2024", PostingDate = "06/10/2024", DueDate = "06/10/2024", TransactionAmount = 30560.11, TransactionAmountReporting = 56000.55 },
    new TransactionEPPlus { CustomerName = "Customer C", Items = "Item 4", TransactionDate = "12/10/2024", PostingDate = "06/10/2024", DueDate = "06/10/2024", TransactionAmount = 1700, TransactionAmountReporting = 100600 }
    // Add more transactions as needed
};

EPPlusExample.CreatePivotTable(transactions);

Now, the output I'm getting with this code is this:
Pivot table with current code

But, I am not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong here because I want to hide the row which has "wow" text coming ad this is the data caption, I want to remove this row without hiding it using EPPlus library.
The final table should look like this i.e. without the Data row("wow" row):
Final output

Anyone is aware how can I achieve the same using the EPPlus library in C#?
Thanks
